# Change selected mat-chips within/after selectionChange

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The concept is that I want to filter displayed information on a page based on which `mat-chips` are selected.

**The HTML:**

```
<mat-chip-list [multiple]="true">
    <mat-chip
       class="item-filter-mat-chip"
       *ngFor="let itemFilter of itemFilters"
       [selectable]="true"
       [selected]="itemFilter.selected"
       [value]="itemFilter"
       (selectionChange)="updateItemFilter($event)"
       (click)="chip.toggleSelected()"
       #chip="matChip">
       {{itemFilter.displayValue}}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

**The TypeScript item:**

```
export interface ItemFilter {
    itemType: ItemType[];
    displayValue: string;
    selected: boolean;
}
```

However I want one of the `mat-chips` to be the "default" that is selected if all other chips are not selected. However it seems like the logic to do the selection change has to happen in `updateItemFilter`, which then creates an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`. This is because I'm trying to change the selection values inside of the `selectionChange` method called.

The situation is this. The default filter is selected. Once a different filter is selected, the default filter should be de-selected. Multiple other filters can be selected. If the default filter is selected, all other filters should be de-selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in, the fix appears to be no longer use (selectionChange) on the mat-chip and instead change the selection AND update the filter inside a custom (click) method.

```
<mat-chip-list [multiple]="true">
    <mat-chip
        class="item-filter-mat-chip"
        *ngFor="let itemFilter of itemFilters"
        [selectable]="true"
        [selected]="itemFilter.selected"
        [value]="itemFilter"
        (click)="updateItemFilter(chip)"
        #chip="matChip">
        {{itemFilter.displayValue}}
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```